# Flag 2 actual vs benchmark readings every rolling 12 hours in SQL Developer Query

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for some help with code in SQL Developer query to flag any 2 temperature readings - every rolling 12 hours - if they are greater than the acceptable benchmark of 101 deg F.

The given data fields are:

- Temp Recorded (DT/TM data type ; down to seconds)
- Reading Value (number data type)
- Patient ID

There are multiple readings taken throughout a patients stay, at random times.

Logically, we can check if two adjacent times total 12 hrs or more & EACH of their temp readings are >101 but not sure how to put it into a CASE statement (unless there's a better SQL syntax).

Will really appreciate if a SQL only solution can be recommended.

Many Thanks

[image]

Giving the code below including the CASE statement as provided by @Gordon Linoff underneath. The below sample code is part of a bigger query joining multiple tables:

SELECT CE.PatientID, CE.ReadingValue, CE.TempRecorded_DT_TM,
(case when sum(case when readingvalue > 101 then 1 else 0 end) over (
partition by patientid
order by dt
range between '12' hour preceding and current row
) >= 2
then 'Y' else 'N'
end) as temp_flag

FROM
edw.se_clinical_event CE
WHERE
CE.PatientID = '176660214'
AND
CE.TempRecorded_DT_TM >= '01-JAN-20'
ORDER BY
TempRecorded_DT_TM

Comment: Interesting question @Curious. Could you please add the expected output as well?Looks like this can be resolved using window functions

Comment: Welcome to SO, please avoid screenshots for data samples. To improve question quality, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the ask's --> to identify 101 F and above ? When-found --> display the 24 hours pre and post the spike ?

Comment: @linusRian: I am in process of checking one thing and will post the output column after that. Please bear with me

Comment: @NizamMadurai: Need this calculated column as a separate field with the output rows meeting the given criteria containing 'Y'/'N' or 1/0 in this 'flagged' column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two readings in 12 hours that are greater than 101, then you can use a rolling sum with a window frame:

```
select t.*,
       (case when sum(case when readingvalue > 101 then 1 else 0 end) over (
                       partition by patientid
                       order by dt
                       range between interval '12' hour preceding and current row
                      ) >= 2
              then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as temp_flag
from t;
```

Comment: Thank You Gordon

Comment: This might be the right solution, I believe. I say that because when I plug in the given solution (after taking out the "Select t.*" portion) to the main SELECT query, it gives the foll. error: "ORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CE.PatientID, CE.ReadingValue, CE.TempRecorded_DT_TM,
       (case when sum(case when readingvalue > 180 then 1 else 0 end) over (
                       partition by patientid
                       order by dt
                       range between '12' hour preceding and current row
                      ) >= 2
              then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as temp_flag

FROM
edw.se_clinical_event CE
WHERE
CE.PatientID = '176660214'
AND
CE.TempRecorded_DT_TM >= '01-JAN-20'
ORDER BY
TempRecorded_DT_TM

Comment: @Curious . . . Remove the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I did but the same error popped up. Can try to attach the screenshot here, if that's permissible.

Comment: @Curious . . . All for the lack of one keyword.  In any case, here is a demonstration that it now works syntactically:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e3fcd7c826299b7e9d3de37cc39e5135.

Comment: Thanks again. I think we are very close. Pasting a few output rows from the solution query to illustrate...

Comment: The cell with red font (5th result row from top) is one result which is incorrectly displaying a Y as the temperature in the given row doesn't fulfill one of the 2 flag criteria.

Comment: |PATIENTID|READINGVALUE| TEMPRECORDED| TEMP_FLAG|
|176130247| 100| 4/8/2020 13:02:16| N|
|176130247| 99| 4/8/2020 16:17:22| N|
|176130247| 102| 3/23/2020 17:20:13| Y|
|176130247| 102| 3/23/2020 20:37:01| Y|
|176130247| 100| 3/24/2020 5:28:49| Y|
|176130247| 103| 3/24/2020 12:00:26| N|
|176130247| 101| 3/24/2020 17:29:05|N|
|176130247| 102| 3/24/2020 21:33:55|Y|
|176130247| 99| 3/25/2020 6:05:50|N|

Comment: my apologies....tried to paste the table but it didn't take the format....can't add any attachments due to company policy